# How to merge two data frames and fill null values with above rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames in python.

First df

```
index   old_index Value1
1       5         1.234
2       9         -0.233
3       872       28.11
```

Second df

```
index   old_index Value2
1       6         -1.234
2       15        0.433
3       23       2.11
```

I woudl like this:

```
index   old_index Value1 Value2
1       5         1.234  NaN
2       6         1.234  -1.234
3       9         -0.233 -1.234
4       15        -0.233  0.433
5       23        -0.233  2.11
6       872       28.11   2.11
```

Thank you for your attention and help.

Comment: Elaborate how you calculate Value1 and Value2 columns?

Comment: This my invented number for examples, but in my project i use moving averenge for two financial instruments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) using method `ffill`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'old_index': [5, 9, 872],
                   'Value 1': [1.234, -0.233, 28.11]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'old_index': [6, 15, 23],
                   'Value 2': [-1.234, 0.433, 2.11]})

new_df = df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer').sort_values(by = 'old_index').fillna(method = 'ffill').reset_index(drop = True)
new_df.index+=1

new_df
  old_index Value 1 Value 2
1   5      1.234    NaN
2   6      1.234    -1.234
3   9      -0.233   -1.234
4   15     -0.233   0.433
5   23     -0.233   2.110
6   872    28.110   2.110
```